# How to I enable Magento 2 developer mode with just Nginx directives?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, developer-mode

I am using Nginx with 2 websites on.
The first Server Config I have is:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name "sh.dev";
   access_log /var/log/nginx/sh-access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/sh-error.log;
   include /var/www/sh/project/nginx.conf;
   set $MAGE_ROOT "/var/www/sh/project";
   set $MAGE_MODE "developer";
}

upstream fastcgi_backend {
   server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

And it is in developer mode, the second site uses a direct name for upstream:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name "magento2.dev";
   access_log /var/log/nginx/magento2-access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/magento2-error.log;
   include /var/www/magento2-test/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
   set $MAGE_ROOT "/var/www/magento2-test/magento2";
   set $MAGE_MODE "developer";
}

upstream fast_backend {
   server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

But I had to manually change the mode with:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Then if you throw an exception is `Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php`:

```
public function run(AppInterface $application)
{

   throw new Exception('Break this thing');

    try {
        try {
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('magento');
            $this->initErrorHandler();
            $this->initObjectManager();
            $this->assertMaintenance();
            $this->assertInstalled();
            $response = $application->launch();
            $response->sendResponse();
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('magento');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('magento');
            if (!$application->catchException($this, $e)) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->terminate($e);
    }
}
```

It should show the error on the front, but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you're using FPM or FastCGI.

For FPM:
`env[MAGE_MODE] = developer`

For FastCGI:
`fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE developer;`

I'm not very experienced with NGINX, so let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 GitHub repo provides some useful examples for that kind of setup.

For instance there is a [`nginx.conf.sample` file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample) where you can find the following:

```
set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
```

As well as the [`.htaccess` file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess) with the following code:

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

Please note that it is not recommended to set the modes on a server level and it's a better practice to use the CLI to do that:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer|production
```

Answer (score 0):

Developer mode is set in app/etc/env.php under the 'MAGE_MODE' key. This value is modified when you run `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`. I don't believe this can be set using server configuration.

See the documentation from Magento for more details - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html